# What is the formula for calculating the odds of having the highest card among N players

Tags: probability, card-games

Given a deck of cards and N players, once I have drawn a card, how can I determine my odds of having the highest card?

I want to know what the formula is for calculating a players odds of having the highest card among players once they have each drawn a card but each player only knows the card he has drawn, the number of other players, and the cards that were in the deck before he drew his card.

*For example, lets assume a fresh deck and 4 players.
If I draw a 7. What are the odds that I will have the highest card among all players?*

---

I intend to use this in some code I am writing as a demonstration, and I just want to make sure my logic is correct.

So far I figure that I need the total number of cards in the deck minus 1 (for the card I drew), lets call it **C** (so for a fresh deck that would be 52, but its still a variable)

Then I need to determine how many cards in the deck are lower than my card, lets call it **L**.

- So for the first other player I need to do **L** / **C**
- And for the second other player I need to do **L** - 1 / **C** - 1
- And for the third other player I need to do **L** - 2 / **C** - 2

And I need to multiply those results together (**L** / **C**) x (**L** - 1 / **C** - 1) x (**L** - 2 / **C** - 2) to get the odds.

Am I right? Also, I am sure there is probably a better way to do this if it is right.

Comment: Not sure the rules are clear.  Are all the cards ranked or are there suits?  Phrased differently, are ties possible?

Comment: @lulu I believe the solution works either way; the only question is whether you choose to include "ties" in the definition of $L$ or not.

Comment: @user326210  Yes, that sounds right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly right.

Here's another way to compute it using combinations. Imagine you take out a card, then spread out the $C$ remaining cards in a row. Your $N$ friends each pick their own card from the row of cards.  If that row contains $L$ cards that are lower than yours, then there are ${L \choose N}$ ways of choosing N cards lower than yours, out of ${C \choose N}$ total ways of choosing any N different cards from this list.

That's the same as:

$$\frac{L!}{N! (L-N)!} \div \frac{C!}{N! (C-N)!} = \frac{L!}{(L-N)!}\div \frac{C!}{(C-N)!} = \frac{L\times(L-1)\times \ldots (L-N+1)}{C\times(C-1)\times\ldots\times(C-N+1)}$$

which is your answer exactly.

Comment: Wow, Thanks.  I am just curious, does this kind of function have a name? One that identifies this kind of formula?

Comment: That's a good question. I'm not sure.  There's terminology for "rising and falling factorials" for example, but that's more of a notation than a combinatoric formula.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that works. It's also equivalent to $\dfrac{\binom{L}{3}}{\binom{C}{3}}$